# C++ - How to add a class object during app is running

Tags: c++

for example we have a program in c++ that when runs shows the following message : (this message is showing in a while(true) loop)

```
1 - Add Student
2 - Show Students
3 - Exit
--------
Enter INDEX:
```

the class code is:

```
class Student{
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    void setInfo(string n, int a){
        name = n;
        age  = a;
    }
    void showInfo(){
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Age : " << age  << endl;
    }
};
```

if we enter 1 as index it should add a new class object to our program ...

how to do this ??

Comment: The only way I can make any sense of this question is that you confuse "class member" with "object of that class" that you probably want to add to some array or vector.

Comment: Sorry... I mean Object!

Comment: You would prompt the user for the new student's name and age, instantiate a new Student object, and store a reference to the new object in your [container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/ "STL Container Classes") object. There really isn't much more we can tell you without doing your homework for you, unless you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define some container for objects. For example you could use standard container `std::vector<Student>` and push new objects to the container.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<Student> students;
//...

Student st;
st.setInfo( "Peter", 18 );

students.push_back( st );

//...
for ( Student &st : students ) st.showInfo();
```

Take into account that function `showInfo` should be declared with qualifier `const`. For example

```
void showInfo() const
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about this ? or tutorial reference ?

Comment: @Monster22 You should read any book on C++. Usually each book on C++ contains a chapter devoted to std::vector. Or you can look through the internet using keyword std::vector.